# Creating a credential for use with SAML in CFML

Tags: certificate, saml, x509

I am trying to create a SAML authentication request in CFML (Railo) with OpenSAML and have got stuck at the point of creating a certificate object to set the public key.

I found soem code that worked well with the private key butusing similar code with the public key certificate does not work. It fails on the call to keyFactory.generatePublic() with : "java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: algid parse error, not a sequence".

Does that mean I need a different format for my public key or that I have the keySpec set wrongly? I have tried using PKCS8EncodedKeySpec and RSAPublicKeySpec  but neither of those work either.  The certificate I'm using is a self signed certificate made with the OpenSSL utils and was created in .crt format.

My Code:

```
    <cfset local.rawKey = replace( arguments.privateKey, "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "" )>
    <cfset local.rawKey = replace( local.rawKey, "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "" )>
    <cfset local.rawKey = trim(local.rawKey)>

    <cfset local.keyBytes   = binaryDecode(local.rawKey, "base64")>
    <cfset local.keySpec    = createObject("java", "java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec")>
    <cfset local.keyFactory = createObject("java", "java.security.KeyFactory").getInstance("RSA")>
    <cfset local.privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(local.keySpec.init(local.keyBytes))>

    <cfset local.rawCert = replace( arguments.certificate, "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "" )>
    <cfset local.rawCert = replace( local.rawCert, "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "" )>
    <cfset local.rawCert = trim(local.rawCert)>

    <cfset local.keyBytes    = binaryDecode(local.rawCert, "base64")>
    <cfset local.keySpec     = createObject("java", "java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec")>
    <cfset local.keyFactory  = createObject("java", "java.security.KeyFactory").getInstance("RSA")>
    <cfset local.certificate = keyFactory.generatePublic(local.keySpec.init(local.keyBytes))>

    <cfset local.credential = _create( "org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.BasicX509Credential" )>

    <cfset local.credential.setPrivateKey( local.privateKey )>
    <cfset local.credential.setEntityCertificate( local.certificate )>

    <cfreturn credential>
</cffunction>
```

Thanks in advance, Kevin

Comment: In case anyone else has to solve this issue. The following appears to do what I need:

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has to solve this issue. The following appears to do what I need:

```
    <cfset local.certBytes    = binaryDecode(local.rawCert, "base64")>
    <cfset local.certStream   = createObject("java", "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream").init(local.certBytes)>
    <cfset local.certFactory  = createObject("java", "java.security.cert.CertificateFactory").getInstance("X.509")>
    <cfset local.certificate = local.certFactory.generateCertificate(local.certStream)>
```